# Start up elastic search on multiple hosts using docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Following this guide: [Install ES using Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/docker.html), I was able to start up an ES cluster with three instances. Unfortunately, these containers are all running in the same host. How could I distribute cluster instances to different hosts(with different IP addresses) and also enable communications between these es instances? Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

Here is the `docker-compose.yaml` file.

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I think ansible would be the best for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> distribute cluster instances to different hosts(with different IP addresses) and also enable communications between these es instances?

This is exactly the use case for Kubernetes or Docker Swarm (if you must have containers).

https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elastic-cloud-on-kubernetes-the-elasticsearch-operator-and-beyond